# How can I read a file from last line to first line in shell?

Tags: bash, shell

I would like to read a line from last line to first line. 
For example:
ant
ball
cat
upto 50 Lines
I need to print it in backwards

Comment: Is `tac` enough (`man tac`)?

Answer (score 1):

***Solution 1st:*** Will be using `tac`:

```
tac Input_file
```

***Solution 2nd:*** In case you don't have `tac` in your system:

```
sed '1!G;h;$!d'  Input_file
```

***Solution 3rd:*** With another `sed` solution too:

```
sed -n '1!G;h;$p' Input_file
```

***Solution 4th:*** Using `awk` too:

```
awk '{a[FNR]=$0} END{for(i=FNR;i>=1;i--){print a[i]}}'   Input_file
```

***Solution 5th:*** `perl` solution:

```
perl -e 'print reverse <>'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `tac [file]` which is like `cat` but prints lines backwards.

from tac manual pages:

> NAME
>
> ```
>    tac - concatenate and print files in reverse
> ```
>
> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
>    tac [OPTION]... [FILE]...
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo -e 1\\n2 |
awk '{b=$0 (b==""?"":ORS b)}END{print b}'
2
1
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '{b=$0 (b==""?"":ORS b)}  # buffer records to the beginning of b
END{print b}'                   # after all records were buffered print b
```

Comment: Even if the your code might be a valid solution for the OP question, it would be recommended to describe the purpose of the code snippet instead of only adding code.